# iOS 9 Constraints Less than or Equal X && Greater than or Equal Y

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

Is it possible to have a constraint that is set to.. for example:

`Less than or equal to 100 but Greater than or equal to 50`

This is so that on smaller devices (I'm having trouble getting views to look good across iPhone 3.5 inch up to 4.7 inch as they're all in the same size class) my views will shrink but only to a certain point so they are still readable?

Comment: Yes, use two constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You need something like:

```
let constraint1 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: i, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .GreaterThanOrEqual, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 100)
let constraint2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: i, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .LessThanOrEqual, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 200)
```

and then add both constraints to the appropriate view.

Comment: Is there any way for this to work without it throwing up constraint errors all over my storyboard?

Comment: You shouldn't have to live with red. Did you set these two constraints in your storyboard? What is the error message you see? If you have two constraints governing the same relationship you may need to lower the priority on one of them.

Comment: @MikeTaverne it says i need constraints for Y position or height

Comment: I'm guessing it's because until it's rendered it, it has no idea how big it's going to be or where anything else is relative to it

Comment: When using constraints, you must set enough constraints for the system to know how to position it both vertically (Y) and horizontally (X). So set a vertical constraint or constraints as well.

Comment: If you're still having issues, then post a picture of your storyboard and any code that is setting constraints.